# Unittest ran 0 tests. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below my program, and I want to test the code, through below test cases
But no testcases are being checked and so the the test program is op-ing following

```
Ran 0 test's in 0.000 sec
OK
```

**capital.py**

```
def captial_text(text):

    return text.title()
```

Here is my test case :

```
import unittest
import capital

class Captest(unittest.TestCase):

    def one_word_test(self):
        text = 'test'
        result = capital.captial_text(text)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Test')

    def two_word_test(self):
        text = 'get things done joints'
        result = capital.captial_text(text)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Get Things Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because your test method names don't start with `test`.

Comment: @khelwood edited the capital_text, that was typo in indentation

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please elobrate!

Comment: ...`"one_word_test".startswith("test") is False`?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I learned that the testcase should start with the word `test`

Here's the code that worked:

```
import unittest
import capital

class Captest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one_word(self):
        text = 'test'
        result = capital.captial_text(text)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Test')

    def test_two_word(self):
        text = 'monty monty joints'
        result = capital.captial_text(text)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Monty Monty Joints')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```